# hypertarget and hyperlink first try

Tags: hyperlink, hypertarget

I am trying to link a word ("Πιστοποιητικό") to a pdf file or a jpg file but I haven't understand where I have to put the file so when someone clicks the hyperlink the file will be revealed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

chapter{Εκπαίδευση}
\hypertarget{Πιστοποιητικό}{} \\ \hyperlink{(Πιστοποιητικό)}{Πιστοποιητικό $4.1$.}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Use \url{path/to/you/file}.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, it didn't have errors but there was a line with the path in greek letters..

Comment: your file has a greek name? Then it will get difficult with pdflatex.

Comment: I have changed the file from an english name to a english name and tried .pdf and .jpg but still I can't do it. However, I would like to have the greek name in the text

Comment: I have tried Also \hypertarget{Πιστοποιητικό}{} \\ \hyperlink{(Πιστοποιητικό)}{Πιστοποιητικό $4.2$ \href{run://home/Petros/auth/Ptyxio.jpg}{Πιστοποιητικό $4.2$}} but it didn't showed up. However, the table of contents has been linked to the chapters without doing anything

Answer (score 1):

I think i did it: I insert the .pdf at the end before `\end{document}` as:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=15cm]{Ptyxio.jpg}
    \centering \selectlanguage{greek}
    \caption{Πιστοποιητικό $4.2$}.
    \hyperlink{Ptyxio.pdf}{Πιστοποιητικό $4.2$}
    \hypertarget{Ptyxio.pdf}{Πιστοποιητικό $4.2$}
\end{figure}
```

and it worked.